# Issue with creating an Object Array

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I'm having an unexpected problem while trying to create an object array.
I've followed a few video tutorials and I don't see what I'm missing.
What I'm trying to create is something that would resemble jet engine fan blades as viewed from the front.

So what I've done to do that is:

1) Create my object, scale and position it to where I want it.
2) Create the empty axis object
3) Select my primary object in edit mode.
4) Add the array modifier
5) Set with the following settings (Count 4, deselect relative offset, select object offset and set it to the empty axis object);

Exhibit A:

[image: Settings]

As you can see, it generates some sort of multiplication of the base object size along the x axis.  Further, if I rotate them, they will distort while hey rotate.  So what did I do wrong?

Exhibit B:

[image: Exhibit A]

Exhibit C

[image: Exhibit C]

Comment: Did you try applying scale for the main object? (Crl+A in Object mode). Note also to reset scale on the empty if it's other than 1.

Comment: Could you, just for visualisation purposes, change a little so that the repeated objects can be discerned? I.e. even if it is not what you finally want, move the empty to get the array non-overlapping. That would help analysing what is going on to cause your problem. Making sure that the shape of the original can be recognised might also help.

Comment: That fixed the scaling up issue, now I have a new one.  When I rotate the empty, the additional objects, which are now the correct size, are being placed along the y axis, each new object one object length apart from the last, like how you might expect to do a staircase by layering one modifier on top of another, but I just have the one array modifier.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've added a third image to better visualize the issues, I hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: I figured it out, the origin points between the empty and the object were offset.

Comment: Make sure the origin (pivot) of your blade is at your desired center of rotation,  (in your case, anywhere on the Y-pointing edge of the blade) then position the empty('s origin) _on_  the blade's origin. If the empty is offset from the origin  of the blade in, say,  Y, then each copy will be offset in Y from the last by the same amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue revealed a second issue, both of which were corrected.

1)  For the first issue, the jet fin object needed to be scaled (Ctrl+A in Object mode, drop down menu select Scale)

2) The follow up issue was due to the origin point of the jet fin object and the empty axis object being offset along the Y axis.  Resetting the jet fin object to zero fixed this.

[image]